# I am relatively new to Intellij, JSON and JAVA, I am struggling to use the JSON-LIB.JAR, many methods do not work, where I could have gone wrong?

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

So I have pressed ctrl+shift+alt+s and popped the json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar in project library and I found that I can now use `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject` fine.  I cannot go on to use `assertEquals` there just doesn't seem to be any appropriate import file that works, I can't use public classes like in the examples either.

I am very much an intermediate beginner and I dont know how I'm expecting to send off encoded json objects to wherever or how I'm going to be listening for them on their way back yet.  I haven't done any tutorials, I want to know if I have installed the libraries first.

Also is their a way that I can have the json library permanently added so that I could just use JSOn freely as and when I felt like it?

Comment: Im seriously wound up by having to not use certain words in the title, im in articulate enough as it is, im not sure if I said what I wanted to all because they want the site to 'look' a certain way, beware techno fascism seriously.

Comment: What is your specifc question?

Comment: oh dammit, that was in the title, sry Im going to have to edit it again

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions here... I'll answer them as best as I can.

> I cannot go on to use `assertEquals` there just doesn't seem to be any appropriate import file that works.

Depending on which `assertEquals` you need, you'll have to import the correct class that contains the method you want. That might be `net.sf.json.test.JSONAssert` located in the json lib jar or `junit.org.Assert` located in the junit jar. If you do a static import on the method, you won't need to prefix with the class; something like

```
import static net.sf.json.test.JSONAssert.assertEquals;
```

but if you need both (the methods have the same name, but take different parameters), you should probably import the classes and use the class prefix when referencing them.

> I can't use public classes like in the examples either

Sorry, but without more information it's impossible to help you on this one. If you can't figure it out, you'll need to provide information about what classes you are unable to access and which error messages you are getting.

It does sound like the classes you mention are located in *another jar*. I.e. if you have access to `JSONObject` but not these other classes, they are not included in the json lib jar. A tip: try [findjar](http://www.findjar.com/) to locate your classes.

> I want to know if I have installed the libraries first.

For what it's worth, I think you're doing it in the right order here. Get the basics working first, before trying to do advanced coding.

> Also is their a way that I can have the json library permanently added so that I could just use JSOn freely as and when I felt like it?

In my opinion, that's not really a good idea. I guess you *can* add it to the `lib` directory of the idea installation (I've never actually tried that myself), but when you start having more than one project, it *will* become a pain. What happens when one project needs the latest and greatest version of the library and your other project for some reason needs an older version?

Believe me, library dependencies will become something you'll need to think about as your projects grow and as you start working on more than one. You'll probably want to use some external build tool, like [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) or [maven](http://maven.apache.org/), to keep track of these dependencies and to make sure your project builds correctly independent of the IDE of choice.

Again, you're doing this in the right order; start with learning the programming language and the IDE before looking into build tools. But please, just add the jar's you need to the project. Don't make these dependencies 'global'.

EDIT: Tip about "[findjar](http://www.findjar.com/)"

Comment: okay thank you, and know with learning JSON i have to try and work out where to send the bloody JSON files, I cant just send them to a server can I?

Comment: Usually, JSON contain data structures that are used when clients and server communicate. You might want to look into jersey as a more "high level" library for using JSON for this purpose in Java.